# How to efficiently construct a numpy array from a large set of data?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a huge list of lists in memory and I wish to convert it into an array, does the naive approach cause python to make a copy of all the data, taking twice the space in memory? Should I convert a list of lists, vector by vector instead by popping?

```
# for instance
list_of_lists = [[...], ..., [...]]
arr = np.array(list_of_lists)
```

Edit:
Is it better to create an empty array of a known size and then populate it incrementally thus avoiding the `list_of_lists` object entirely? Could this be accomplished by something as simply as `some_array[i] = some_list_of_float_values`?

Comment: Note that a `numpy array` and a python `list` are completely different concepts. If you have some time, I would suggest having a look at this publication: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.1523.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just puttign theis here as it's a bit long for a comment.

Have you read the numpy documentation for [`array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array)?

```py
numpy.array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0)
"""
...
copy : bool, optional
  If true (default), then the object is copied. Otherwise, a copy will
  only be made if __array__ returns a copy, if obj is a nested sequence,
  or if a copy is needed to satisfy any of the other requirements (dtype,
  order, etc.).
...
"""
```

When you say you don't want to *copy* the data of the original array when creating the `numpy` array, what data structure are you hoping to end up with?

A lot of the speed up you get from using `numpy` is because the C arrays that are created are contiguous in memory. An array in python is just an array of pointers to objects, so you have to go and find the objects every time - which isn't the case in `numpy`, as it's not written in python.

If you want to just have the `numpy` array reference the python arrays in your 2D array, then you'll lose the performance gains.

if you do `np.array(my_2D_python_array, copy=False)` i don't know what it will actually produce, but you could easily test it yourself. Look at the shape of the array, and see what kind of objects it houses.

If you want the numpy array to be contiguous though, as some point you're going to have to allocate all of the memory it needs (which if it's as large as you're suggesting, it sounds like it might be difficult to find a contiguous section large enough).

Sorry that was pretty rambling, just a comment. How big are the actual arrays you're looking at?

Here's a plot of the cpu usage and memory usage of a small sample program:

```
from __future__ import division

#Make a large python 2D array
N, M = 10000, 18750
print "%i x %i = %i doubles = %f GB" % (N, M, N * M, N*M*8/10**9)

#grab pid to moniter memory and cpu usage
import os
pid = os.getpid()

os.system("python moniter.py -p " + str(pid) + " &")


print "building python matrix"
large_2d_array = [[n + m*M for n in range(N)] for m in range(M)]


import numpy
from datetime import datetime

print datetime.now(), "creating numpy array with copy"
np1 = numpy.array(large_2d_array, copy=True)
print datetime.now(), "deleting array"
del(np1)


print datetime.now(), "creating numpy array with copy"
np1 = numpy.array(large_2d_array, copy=False)
print datetime.now(), "deleting array"
del(np1)
```

[image]

1, 2, and 3 are the points where each of the matrices finish being created. Note that the native python array takes up much more memory than the numpy ones - python objects each have their own overhead, and the lists are lists of objects. For the numpy array this is not the case, so it is considerably smaller.

Also note that using the copy on the python object has no effect - new data is always created. You could get around this by creating a numpy array of python objects (using `dtype=object`), but i wouldn't advise it.

Comment: It's about 1.5gb 10k x 150k but I should be able to build the numpy array vector by vector? Would it then realoc a bunch of times? I am not sure how to pull this off but I don't need or want the `list_of_lists` and the numpy array on the same time.

Comment: Okay, first off, an array that's 10K by 150K is going to be a lot more than 1.5GB; 6GB for 32bit ints, 12GB for doubles.

Comment: No, I meant in bytes. The float vector is 150kb :) It's only 30+k floats

Comment: Ah okay!! that's fine. I'm just looking at the usage now of the different methods. I'll put some plots in shortly.

Comment: You can always build the numpy array, and then just `del(list_of_lists)` afterwards.

Comment: How do I create an "empty" array and populate it incrementally and is that going to improve (lessen) memory usage? Do I just do something like `some_array[i] = some_list_of_floats`

Comment: I usually use `numpy.zeros` to initialize numpy arrays. You can give it `dtype` to pick the type of the elements (`float64` is default).

Comment: well in numpy you can create an "empty" array and then set the values yourself, or as @jpkotta says you can use `zeros` (or the other similar methods). These are all documented in the numpy documentation though...

Comment: Yeah, I should have clarified that I use `zeros` for "empty" arrays (numpy arrays are fixed size).  If you already have a list that you want to turn into an array, it's probably best to just initialize with the list.  Which is better?  Profile it and find out.